# Recalculate sheet excel in VBA when getting numbers from cells with Cells.Value

Tags: vba, excel, auto-update

Here is a simple example to explain what I want to do:

```
Function fun(X As Double)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Y = Cells(2, "C").Value

    fun = X + Y

End Function
```

So, if I am changing the value of `X` inside the excel sheet, result of `fun` will change as expected, but if I change the value of `Y`, nothing happens. I must change `X` again so the function will get the new value of `Y` and calculate the proper value.

Is there a way to add code in this VBA function so the result of `fun` will automatically update with a change of value for `Y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Application.Volatile` to your function as the first line.

```
Function fun(X As Double)
    Application.Volatile
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Dim Y As Long

    Y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "C").Value

    fun = X + Y

End Function
```

The assignment to Y should be done directly, not by activating a worksheet.